# Android Navigation - Is it possible to restore a bundle from upper fragment with popBackStack method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I was trying to pass data between fragments while I was passing from upper fragment to down fragment, but I don't want to use the navigate method. It adds a new destination to the process history, but I want back to the previous fragment, restore it data and refresh the view.
Is it possible to do it with NavController and popBackStack method?

Comment: I think new navigation depend on LiveData to achieve that between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours I found a strange solution. `findNavController().popBackStack()` cannot pass data to the previous fragment, but we can do it using the `findNavController().graph.defaultArguments`, set the data in one fragment, and get the data in the second one. I believe someone will find the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same problem and I have used below solution which is working, But i am not sure its correct way or not.

```
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.id_of_fragment_one, true).build()
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.id_of_fragment_one, bundleOf("id" to model), navOptions)
```