# recyclerview jetpack bug - pressing back button twice to go to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm using the Jetpack navigation component with a navhost and navgraph. In my `categoriesFragment`, I have a `RecyclerView` that displays the current list of categories in the database. It's attached to a `LiveData` implementation of the SQL that grabs all the categories from the database.

Whenever I add a category to the database from a dialog window, I navigate back to the `categoriesFragment` while passing data back to it and insert the category into the database from within the `categoriesFragment`. It shows the updated list of categories in the `RecyclerView` of the `categoriesFragment` fine,  but the problem is I have to press the back button 2 times to go back to the previous fragment. What could be the issue? Thanks.

**Fragment:**

```
package com.example.pomoplay.ui.main

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SearchView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.pomoplay.CategoriesRecyclerAdapter
import com.example.pomoplay.PomoPlayObservablesSingleton
import com.example.pomoplay.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_categories.*

class CategoriesFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private var newCategoryCreated: Boolean = false
    lateinit var navController: NavController
    private var adapter: CategoriesRecyclerAdapter? = null
    private val viewModel: CategoriesFragmentViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnCreateView() called")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnViewCreated() called")
        Log.i("Lifecycle-Frag-Bundle", savedInstanceState.toString())

        categories_searchview.isIconified = false
        categories_searchview.isFocusable = true
        categories_searchview.clearFocus()

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        observerSetup()
        recyclerSetup()

        var searchView = categories_searchview
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

        fab_new_category.setOnClickListener {
           navController.navigate(R.id.action_categoriesFragment_to_newCategoryDialogFragment)
        }

        if(!arguments?.isEmpty!! && newCategoryCreated){

            var args = CategoriesFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)
            if(args.fromNewCategoryDialog){
                var category = args.category

                viewModel.insertCategory(category)

                PomoPlayObservablesSingleton.newCategoryCreatedSubject.onNext(false)

            }

        }

        searchView.setOnCloseListener {

            viewModel.setLastSearchQuery("")
            navController.navigate(R.id.categoriesFragment)

            true
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {

        super.onResume()

        if(viewModel.getLastSearchQuery() != null && viewModel.getLastSearchQuery().toString() != "")
        {
            categories_searchview.requestFocusFromTouch()
            categories_searchview.setQuery(viewModel.getLastSearchQuery().toString(), true)
        }   

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnResume() called")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        categories_searchview.clearFocus()
        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnPause() called")

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnStop() called")

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnDestroyView() called")

        //PomoPlayObservablesSingleton.newCategoryCreatedSubject.onNext(false)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnDestroy() called")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnDetach() called")

    }

    private fun observerSetup() {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "observerSetup() called")


        viewModel.getSearchCategoriesNameResults().observe(this,androidx.lifecycle.Observer { categories ->

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "getSearchCategoriesNameResults observable value received")

            adapter?.setCategoryList(categories)

        })

        viewModel.getAllCategories()?.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { categories ->

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "getAllCategories observable value received")


            if(categories.isNotEmpty()){

                    adapter?.setCategoryList(categories.sortedBy { category -> category.name?.toLowerCase() })

                category_not_found_bubble.visibility = View.GONE
                category_not_found_text.visibility = View.GONE

                }
                else{
                    category_not_found_bubble.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    category_not_found_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
        })

        PomoPlayObservablesSingleton.newCategoryCreatedSubject.subscribe{comp -> newCategoryCreated = comp }

    }

    private fun recyclerSetup() {
        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "recyclerSetup() called")

        adapter = context?.let { CategoriesRecyclerAdapter(it) }
        categories_list?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        categories_list?.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "onQueryTextSubmit() called")

        var q = query?.toLowerCase()?.trim()?.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " ")
        setLastSearchQuery(q.toString())

        viewModel.searchCategoriesByName(viewModel.getLastSearchQuery().toString())

        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "onQueryTextChange() called")

        return false
    }

        private fun setLastSearchQuery(q: String?) {

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "setLastSearchQuery() called")

            viewModel.setLastSearchQuery(q.toString())
        }
```

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
package com.example.pomoplay

import android.content.Context
import android.view.*
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoriesFragmentDirections

class CategoriesRecyclerAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    private var categoriesList: List<Category> = emptyList()
    private val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    fun setCategoryList(categories: List<Category>) {
        categoriesList = categories
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = categoriesList.size


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val category = categoriesList[position]
        holder.textCategoryTitle?.text = category?.name
        holder.textCategoryDescription?.text = category?.desc

        holder.optMenu.setOnClickListener {
            val popup = PopupMenu(context, holder.optMenu)
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.category_menu)
            //adding click listener
            //adding click listener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener,
                PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
                override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    return when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.app_settings -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "it works from recyclerview! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            })


            //displaying the popup
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show()
        }

        holder.textCategoryTitle?.setOnClickListener {
            var navController = Navigation.findNavController(it)

            var action = CategoriesFragmentDirections.actionCategoriesFragmentToCategoryFragment(category, fromCategoriesFragmentTitle = true)

            PomoPlayObservablesSingleton.newCategoryCreatedSubject.onNext(false)

            navController.navigate(action)
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textCategoryTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView?>(R.id.categories_list_item_title)
        val textCategoryDescription = itemView.findViewById<TextView?>(R.id.categories_list_item_description)
        val optMenu: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optmenu)

    }
```

**RecyclerView Layout:**

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categories_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categories_searchview"
        tools:listitem="@layout/categories_list_item">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**New Category Dialog:**

```
package com.example.pomoplay.ui.main

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.example.pomoplay.Category
import com.example.pomoplay.PomoPlayObservablesSingleton
import com.example.pomoplay.R

class NewCategoryDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var categoryNameEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var categoryDescEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(parentFragment?.view!!)

        var catList = ArrayList<String>()
        catList.add("Test Item 1")
        catList.add("Test Item 2")

        val view =
            requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_category_dialog, null)

        categoryNameEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_category_name) as EditText
        categoryDescEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_category_desc) as EditText

        return activity?.let { it ->

            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setTitle("Testing")
                .setPositiveButton(
                    "ok"
                ) { _, id ->

                    var cat = Category(categoryNameEditText.text.toString().trim().replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " "), categoryDescEditText.text.toString().trim().replace("\\s+"," "))

                    var action = NewCategoryDialogFragmentDirections.actionNewCategoryDialogFragmentToCategoriesFragment(cat, fromNewCategoryDialog = true)

                    PomoPlayObservablesSingleton.newCategoryCreatedSubject.onNext(true)

                    navController.navigate(action)

                }
                .setNegativeButton("cancel") { _, id ->

                }
                .setView(view)


            var spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.dialog_new_category_spinner)

            var spinnerAdapter =
                context?.let {
                    ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        it,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        catList
                    )
                }


            spinnerAdapter?.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter



            val dialog = builder.create()

            dialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
                (dialog as AlertDialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isEnabled = categoryNameEditText.text.isNotBlank() && categoryNameEditText.text.isNotEmpty()
            }

            categoryNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun onTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int,
                    count: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int,
                    after: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) { // Check if edittext is empty

                    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isEnabled =
                        !(categoryNameEditText.text.isBlank() || categoryNameEditText.text.isEmpty())


                }

            })

            dialog

        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

}
```

**NavGraph:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/categoriesFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/clockFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.ClockFragment"
        android:label="Pomo Clock"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_clock" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoryFragment"
        android:label="Category"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_clockFragment"
            app:destination="@id/clockFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_newTaskDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newTaskDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="pomotask"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.PomoTask"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromNewTaskDialog"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromCategoriesFragmentTitle"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoriesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="Categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_newCategoryDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newCategoryDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromNewCategoryDialog"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newCategoryDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewCategoryDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_category_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newCategoryDialogFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesFragment" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newTaskDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewTaskDialogFragment"
        android:label="fragment_new_task_dialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_task_dialog" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newTaskDialogFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Which part is the back code? You should also show us your `nav_graph`.

Comment: @JohnJoe Why would I need to implement the back code? When I press the back button, it should simply go to the previous fragment on the back stack, right?

Comment: @JohnJoe I updated the question to include the ```nav_graph```

Comment: @JohnJoe The dialog is a separate fragment all together. And When I press the ok button on the dialog, it navigates back to the CategoriesFragment. Does this cause the CategoriesFragment to be added to the backstack once more? Is this why I have to press the back button 2 times to exit the fragment? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: What does this line do  `var action = NewCategoryDialogFragmentDirections.actionNewCategoryDialogFragmentToCategoriesFragment(cat, fromNewCategoryDialog = true)`  ? Is it calling the previous fragment?

Comment: @JohnJoe It's using the safeArgs parameters specified in the CategoriesFragment. You'll notice that in the ```nav_graph```. I'm putting the category object I created above that line into an action object which I pass to the CateogriesFragment by navigating to that previous fragment, which I do by the following: ```navController.navigate(R.id.action_newCategoryDialogFragment_to_categoriesFragment)```

Comment: Once you click the ok button in dialog, it will back to previous fragment automatically?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes. It automatically goes back to the previous fragment when it executes the following code which is in the OK button press code in the dialog fragment: ```navController.navigate(R.id.action_newCategoryDialogFragment_to_categoriesFragment)```. Also, the dialog fragment shows up on the screen as a dialog which causes the Categories fragment to draken in the background while still visible.

Comment: Try remove `navController.navigate(action)` and place with `navController()?.popBackStack()` ,then click the back button in category fragment. See what is the result.

Comment: @JohnJoe Ok, that's working. It's no longer requiring me to press the back button twice. I also removed the part where I create the action object. Instead, I simply just insert the category object into the database from within the OK button-press code. I wonder why my previous code was causing the Categories fragment to be added to the backstack again. But, thanks for the help!

Comment: Simple because you are calling `navController.navigate()` again.

Comment: @JohnJoe But what if you have to pass data from the dialog to the paused fragment? Don't you have to package the data and then navigate to the paused fragment, which means you have to call ```navController.navigate()```?

Comment: What paused fragment are you referring?

Comment: @JohnJoe This is what I'm doing. When I press the add-new-category FAB button in the CategoriesFragment, it pops up the NewCategoriesDialog fragment in the foreground which keeps the CategoriesFragment visible in the background but drakened in color. So, when I press the OK buton in the dialog fragment for the new category with the new category name and description, I have to pass the data to the Categories fragment which then is processed in there and inserted in the database.

Comment: @JohnJoe Why did you delete your answer? It was correct.

Comment: But my answer doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: @JohnJoe Ok. But thanks for the help. You solved a major road block for me.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687800/android-navigation-is-it-possible-to-restore-a-bundle-from-upper-fragment-with

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `navController.navigate(action)` again which will create `CategoryFragment` again.

To back to previous fragment, you should use `navController()?.popBackStack()`.

Comment: The ```recyclerview``` that I have in the previous fragment should show an updated list of tasks which is returned with a call to an SQL statement. The problem is that if I simply do a ```popbackstack()```, it goes to the previous fragment with the ```recyclerview``` but does not reload the fragment so that the ```recyclerview's``` list can be updated. In fact, none of its lifecycle methods are called. It shows the old ```recyclerview``` list. Is there a way to reload the fragment in order to call the SQL again and update the list in the ```recyclerview```?

Comment: Yes. You can override `onResume()` in your Category Fragement.

Comment: I have tried that already, but it does not work. None of the Category Fragment's lifecycle methods including ```onResume()``` are being called.

Comment: This line not printing? `Log.i("Lifecycle-Fragment", "OnResume() called")`

Comment: Right. It is not printing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If I want to pass data/arguments back to the previous fragment from a dialog fragment and, at the same time, solve the problem of having to press the back button twice, I could use the code in my original question unchanged and just use the `Pop Behavior` options in the `Action` attributes of the `Action` that goes from the `newCategoryDialogFragment` to the `categoriesFragment`.

To test it out, I kept the original code in place and in the `Pop Behavior` section, I set the `Pop To` attribute to `categoriesFragment` and checked the `Inclusive` checkbox.

I had to check the `Inclusive` checkbox, because when I navigate to the `categoresFragment` from the `newCategoryDialogFragment` with `navcontroller.navigate(action)`, it adds the `categoriesFragment` again to the backstack; the inclusive property removes this duplicate. Here's a screenshot of the `Pop Behavior` section:

[image]